# how to transform json to pageVo using Reactive Cocoa + MVVM

Tags: objective-c, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

Rest return json:

```js
{  
    "respCode": {  
    "code": 0,  
    "msg": "success"  
  },  
  "timestamp": 1438004437838,  
  "pageVo": {  
    "pageSize": 5,  
    "pageNo": 1,  
    "recordSize": 2,  
    "hasNextPage": false,  
    "hasPrevPage": false,  
    "pageTotal": 1,    
    "data": [  
      {  
        "id": 1,  
        "status": 1,  
        "createDate": 1437747090000,  
        "modifyDate": 1437748290000,  
        "userId": 1,  
        "like": 0,  
        "relay": 0,  
        "category": 0,  
        "lat": "133.333",  
        "lng": "13.999",  
        "user": {  
          "id": 1,  
          "nickname": "Jack",  
          "avatar": "http://www.xx.xxxx/xxxx/xxx.jpg"
        },  
        "itemsPrices": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "itemsId": 1,
            "price": 188.0,
            "title": "world",
            "x": "123.1223",
            "y": "123.4444"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "status": 1,
            "itemsId": 1,  
            "price": 188.0,
            "title": "world2",
            "x": "123.1223",
            "y": "123.4444"
          }
        ],
        "itemsPictures": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "itemsId": 1,
            "url": "http://xxx.xxxx.xxx",
            "isCover": true
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "status": 1,
            "itemsId": 1,
            "url": "http://xxx.xxxx.xxx",
            "isCover": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "status": 1,
        "createDate": 1437747128000,
        "modifyDate": 1437748341000,
        "userId": 1,
        "like": 0,
        "relay": 0,
        "category": 0,
        "lat": "133.333",
        "lng": "13.999",
        "user": {
          "id": 2,
          "nickname": "world",
          "avatar": "http://www.xx.xxxx/xxxx/xxx.jpg"
        },
        "itemsPrices": [
          {
            "status": 1
          }
        ],
        "itemsPictures": [
          {
            "status": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "firstIndex": null,
    "lastIndex": null
  }
}
```

rest fetch data:

```
@implementation ZCAPIManager (Items)  
- (RACSignal *)fetchItems {
    NSString *url = @"http://localhost:8080/zc_mobile/items/list?        pageNo=1&pageSize=5";
    RACSignal *resultSignal = [self requestGetWithRelativePath:url parameters:nil resultClass:nil listKey:nil];

return [[resultSignal subscribeOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] map:^id(RACTuple *jsonAndHeaders) {
    NSDictionary *jsonResult = jsonAndHeaders.first;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = jsonAndHeaders.second;

    ZCItemsViewModel *itemsViewModel = [[ZCItemsViewModel alloc] init];
    ZCRespCode *respCode = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[ZCRespCode class] fromJSONDictionary:jsonResult[ZCJSONResponseResponseCodeKey] error:nil];

    itemsViewModel.respCode = respCode;

    if(ZCResponseCodeSuccess == respCode.code && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        NSDictionary *pageVoDictionary = jsonResult[ZCJSONResponsePageVoKey];
        ZCPageVo *pageVo = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[ZCPageVo class] fromJSONDictionary:pageVoDictionary error:nil];
        itemsViewModel.pageVo = pageVo;

        itemsViewModel.data = [[[pageVoDictionary[ZCJSONResponseDataKey] rac_sequence] map:^id(NSDictionary *itemsDictionary) {
            ZCItems *items = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[ZCItems class] fromJSONDictionary:itemsDictionary error:nil];
            return items;
        }] array];
    }

    return itemsViewModel;
}] ;
}

@end

ViewModel:
@interface ZCBaseViewModel : RVMViewModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) ZCRespCode *respCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ZCPageVo *pageVo;

@end

@interface ZCItemsViewModel : ZCBaseViewModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *executeFetch;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *data;

@end

@interface ZCItemsViewModel : ZCBaseViewModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) RACSignal *executeFetch;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *data;

@end
```

Unit test / ViewController like this:

```
- (void)testRequestWithMethod_new3 {

    hxRunInMainLoop(^(BOOL *done) {

        RACSignal *loadItems = [[[ZCAPIManager alloc] init] fetchItems];
        RAC(self, itemsViewModel) = loadItems;
        [loadItems subscribeNext:^(id x) {
            NSLog(@"x = %@\n",x);
            NSLog(@"itemsViewModel = %@", self.itemsViewModel);
            *done = YES;
        }];

    });
}
```

This way is right? Do you have other way to solve this problem with Complex json to ViewModel.
This way is right? Do you have other way to solve this problem with Complex json to ViewModel.

If JSON conversion logic inside ViewModel. The ViewModel init method look like this?

```
- (instancetype) init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        ZCAPIManager *apiManager = [[ZCAPIManager alloc] init];

        self.executeFetch = [[[apiManager fetchItems] subscribeOn:    [RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] map:^id(RACTuple *jsonAndHeaders) {
            NSDictionary *jsonResult = jsonAndHeaders.first;
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = jsonAndHeaders.second;

            ZCRespCode *respCode = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[ZCRespCode class] fromJSONDictionary:jsonResult[ZCJSONResponseResponseCodeKey] error:nil];

            self.respCode = respCode;

            if(ZCResponseCodeSuccess == respCode.code && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                NSDictionary *pageVoDictionary = jsonResult[ZCJSONResponsePageVoKey];
                ZCPageVo *pageVo = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[ZCPageVo class] fromJSONDictionary:pageVoDictionary error:nil];
                self.pageVo = pageVo;

                self.data = [[[pageVoDictionary[ZCJSONResponseDataKey] rac_sequence] map:^id(NSDictionary *itemsDictionary) {
                    ZCItems *items = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[ZCItems class] fromJSONDictionary:itemsDictionary error:nil];
                    return items;
                }] array];
            }
            return self;

        }];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Do it right? What is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me be a bit catchy:

1. Your test code subscribes to this signal two times, why?
2. There's great framework to test reactive cocoa. [Expecta](https://github.com/specta/expecta) + [LLReactiveMatchers](https://github.com/lawrencelomax/LLReactiveMatchers)
3. Your test code makes real network request which makes your test slow and network dependent. You should have injected some mock API network manager. Maybe DI with [Typhoon](http://typhoonframework.org)?
4. Your code doesn't populate JSON error
5. I wouldn't merge to responsibilities in one method: making a request and parsing. These are separate principles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.     
1、I just subscribe once in my test code . why two time? I don't know where the subscribed twice?     
2、I wanted JSON conversion logic inside ViewModel. But I don't know how to operate it. Because the returned JSON will eventually be converted into a ViewModel, is himself. Do this logic in ViewModel init method? Signal return an object but i have three or more object need to be return .

Comment: 1. 1st time when you bind it to variable, 2nd when you explicitly subscribe by `subscribeNext`

Comment: 2. I would create create RACSignal(Model) extension for parsing. VM shouldn't be bind with one particular Model.